# Using regex with Elastica

Tags: php, regex, elasticsearch, elastica

I have been using [elastisearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) trough [elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) recently and I am having problems using the regexp.

Here is my problem:

I need to find **all instances of my "Foo" entity with the "name" NOT begin by a letter**.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $name; // example: "1&1", "OVH", "Aliyun" ...
}
```

According to elasticsearch documentation, there is a "regexp" [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html) but I couldn't find the implementation in elastica.

I have tried:

```
\Elastica\Query\Prefix(); //Apparently it doesn't handle the regexp
```

From the documentation I could get:

```
$reg = '@&~(foo.+)'; # anything except string beginning with "foo"
```

Basically **I can't find what type of query class I should use from Elastica.**

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Elastica but a [quick search](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/search?q=regexp&ref=cmdform&type=Code) pointed me to the only class that implements `Regexp`:

[`\Elastica\Filter\Regexp`](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/lib/Elastica/Filter/Regexp.php)

And an example of it's use in the test case:

[`Elastica\test\lib\Elastica\Test\Filter\RegexpTest`](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/test/lib/Elastica/Test/Filter/RegexpTest.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, added few days after I ask the question !